# Supporting two storyboards

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, xamarin, xcode-storyboard

I have an app with a medium-sized storyboard, which is complicated enough for me not to want to mess around with it too much.

I want to copy this storyboard and change the color scheme and let the user select which color scheme to use.

My question is: can I programmatically select which storyboard will be used by default on startup? If yes - how do I do that?

I looked at a somewhat related question: [Storyboards Orientation Support in Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.x ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822325/storyboards-orientation-support-in-xcode-4-5-and-ios-6-x)

Based on that code I made an extension method:

```
   static bool IsStoryboardLoading {get;set;}

   public static T ConsiderSwitchingStoryboard<T> (this UIViewController from) where T: UIViewController
   {
       if (!IsStoryboardLoading && LocalStorage.Instance.IsWhiteScheme && false) {
           try {
               IsStoryboardLoading = true; 
               UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard_WHITE", NSBundle.MainBundle);
               T whiteView = storyboard.InstantiateViewController (typeof(T).Name) as T;

               from.PresentViewController (whiteView, false, null); 
               return whiteView;
           } finally {
               IsStoryboardLoading = false; 
           }  
       } 
       return null;
   }
}
```

and then I use it in `ViewDidAppear` override:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
    this.ConsiderSwitchingStoryboard<MyViewController> ();
}
```

This code works in some cases but in others it causes an error when performing a `push` segue:

```
NSGenericException Reason: Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'segSearchResults'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to just use 1 Storyboard and have 2 sets of controllers in the same storyboard. Just use different storyboard ids for the controllers. You can use the same class on those if needed.

For example:

```
var whiteController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyWhiteController") as MyController;
var blueController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyBlueController") as MyController;
```

Both could create an instance of `MyController`, but pull out different layouts from the same storyboard file.

Another option is to use `UIAppearance` to dynamically set a "style" on all controls of a certain type in your app.

For example, to set the default `UIBarButtonItem` image throughout your app:

```
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile("yourpng.png"), UIControlState.Normal, UIBarMetrics.Detault);
```

(You might check my parameters there)

Comment: The storyboard is already busy enough, this would mean doubling its size. Plus I'll still have to have the same code as above with the same issues. So really, there's no benefit of this proposal.

Comment: Why can't you change colors from code then? Using UIAppearrance would be much better candidate for this than making the changes in storyboards.

Comment: I can but I would much rather create a XSD to transform my main storyboard into a second one with changed colors upon build and not have to write code for each item that has to be changed

Comment: That seems like an equivalent amount of work, `UIAppearance` is a more standard solution and would be more obvious to other Xamarin.iOS developers. I will make an edit later today on how you can make this work though, since it already sounds like you setup the XSD.

Comment: I haven't set up the XSD yet. I'm looking for a way that would be equivalent of editing the info.plist to replace the default storyboard - the less code involved and the less spread it is throughout my other code - the better.

Comment: UIAppearance would only be a few lines of C#, it is the equivalent of CSS on iOS.

Comment: I looked it up and I see what it does, it will likely work for what I need it to. Please update your answer with a small sample so I can mark it as an answer. Thank you much!