# Storyboard orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I'm creating one iOS app and I'm using Storyboards to create the UIs. App should support iOS5 and above devices

In MainStoryboard_iPhone and MainStoryboard_iPad I have the UIs designed for the portrait mode.

Now I need to design them to work in landscape mode as well.

What is the best way to do that? Do I need to create another storyboard for landscape mode or is there a easier way?

For each UI I have set a background image using Imageview. Is there a image naming convention, when I used for e.g like myimage-Landscape.png it automatically detects the landscape mode image and sets it?

Comment: Check this for storyboard orientation:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803524/storyboards-orientation-support-for-xcode-4-2?rq=1

Comment: link is looking good. But form the link I found We will need to create two different story board. this is not Proper solution. do We have any other way so I can reuse my single store board for both orientation.

Comment: You will need to learn and use the Constraints

Answer (score 1):

You could go ahead and create a separate storyboard.

However the actual recommended Apple Guidelines would state that this is what Constraints are designed for.

**I learnt from this fantastic tutorial:**

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2